# pgAdmin 4 PostgreSQL Query Tool always showed disconnect logo

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, pgadmin-4

I have a server in Heroku that run in PostgreSQL. 
This is my first time deploy to Heroku and try to running in PostgreSQL (actually this also my first time PostgreSQL).

I Have a problem with this query tool feature. I NEVER able to write some SQL commands with this DMBS. I'm still wondering why I can't even write a single query with this.

I try to download and install PostgreSQL locally and try to run the query tool, it perfectly run with no even disconnect logo (and with no SLOW LOADING)

[image: Screenshot]

And the host is on AWS. And the other problem maybe with the very slow loading that I have experienced with this. 
It also annoy me so much in fact.

But I really have no idea why I cant even write a single query with this.
Any help would be really appreciated.

[I have try this]

1. I have try to delete the folder in Roaming and need to re connect the server from the beginning.
2. I have try to downgraded my PostgreSQL to 9.6 with pgAdmin built-in (before I was using only pgAdmin 4), and no result.
3. Of course I have try to restart this machine for several times but still no luck.
4. I think the Wi-Fi is not the problem.